# QTP AOM code to enable image capture on script failure is not working

Tags: hp-uft

QTP AOM code to enable image capture on script failure is not working

I am using the below code to enable the QTP Screen Capture option but it's not storing any screenshots:

Code:

```
Dim App
Dim qtTest

'Create the QTP Application object
Set App = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")

'If QTP is notopen then open it
If  App.launched <> True then

App.Launch

End If

'Make the QuickTest application visible
App.Visible = True

'Set QuickTest run options
'Instruct QuickTest to perform next step when error occurs

App.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError"
App.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
App.Options.Run.ViewResults = True

'Open the test in read-only mode
App.Open "D:\GUITest4", True

'set run settings for the test
Set qtTest = App.Test

'Instruct QuickTest to perform next step when error occurs
qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError = "NextStep"

'Run the test
qtTest.Run


'Check the results of the test run
MsgBox qtTest.LastRunResults.Status

' Close the test
qtTest.Close

'Close QTP
'App.quit

'Release Object
Set qtTest = Nothing
Set App = Nothing
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to capture screenshots:

set obj = Desktop
 obj.capturebitmap strFileName & ".png"

To have the screenshot embedded in results itself, give the path of results in strFileName  parameter as:
strFileName  = Environment.Value("ResultDir") & "\" &  Mid(Environment.Value("ActionName"), 1, 15) & filename.png

Answer (score 0):

Using **QTP AOM** we can capture the screenshot which will be stored in the results folder , can be controlled via below code.

```
Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError"
qtApp.Open "C:\Tests\Test1", True

Set qtTest = qtApp.Test

Set qtResultsOpt = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions")
```

Create the Run Results Options object

```
qtResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = "C:\Tests\Test1\Res1"
```

Set the results location

```
 qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt
```

Run the test

```
qtTest.Close
```

Hope it helps, let me know the results